# I am just trying to show an image in a GUI. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, tkinter

I am trying to display an image in a GUI, and don't understand what is wrong. I keep getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_PhotoImage__photo'
```

What should my code (especially the line with `my_img=...`) look like?

My Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk,Image

my_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("iu.jpeg"))
my_label = Label(image=my_img)
my_label.pack()


root = Tk()
root.title("ICON PRACTICE")
root.iconbitmap('iu.ico')

button_quit = Button(root, text = "EXIT", command=root.quit)
button_quit.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

The full error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    my_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("test.png"))
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/ImageTk.py", line 112, in __init__
    self.__photo = tkinter.PhotoImage(**kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 4064, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3997, in __init__
    raise RuntimeError('Too early to create image')
RuntimeError: Too early to create image
Exception ignored in: <function PhotoImage.__del__ at 0x7f7148fadc10>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/ImageTk.py", line 118, in __del__
    name = self.__photo.name
AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_PhotoImage__photo'
```

Comment: You should put the three lines (after import statements) after creating `root` instance, i.e. before `button_quit = ...`.

Comment: Have you tried moving the creation of the root window before you tried creating the image? Also, please tell us what line created the error. We can guess, but it's better if we don't have to.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a parent/master that initialize a tkinter class?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59008955/7414759)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this, its probably because you create the root object after opening the image and creating the photo object.

```
import os
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk,Image

root= Tk()
i = Image.open("C:/path/to/the/image/directory/image.png") 
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(i)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why not just pass the full pathname of the image to `Image.open()`?  Changing current directory to the image directory may affect the other part of the program.

Comment: Also the import statements: `import Image`, `import ImageTk` and `from PIL import Tk` are incorrect.

Comment: If the path was the problem, the OP would have gotten a different error.

Answer (score 0):

The `Label` widget will only work after `root = Tk()` (`Tk()` starts the underlying Tcl interpreter) is declared. Then, all child widgets must have root as their first parameter (e.g., `Label(root, text='hi')`). You started the interpreter after you tried to use it, so Python raised an exception.